# Should I place my game in a class pygame?

Tags: python, class, pygame, game-development

I just started learning pygame, and I'm no expert to Python, either. But when I make a game, should I have the game inside a class like in Tkinter? None of the tutorials I watched did, but I kind of like having the classes variables instead of having to worry about global variables or returning values. Are there clear advantages or disadvantages? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - you should not put your whole game inside a class, unless it makes sense.
I consider writing these 2d games one of the best forms of learning OO programming means you will use classes and inheritance when it is comfortable in your game design - not just for the sake of it.

And Pygame is a module that do not require (and sometimes do  not allow) you to produce your work by doing class inheritance.If you try to inherit from Pygame's `Surface`  class for example, you will find out that your customized class can't be passed as parameter for functions expecting a Surface.

However, Pygame *is* designed for you to inherit one class: `pygame.sprite.Sprite`. As long as you make use of `pygame.sprite.Group`s and its derivatives for object containers in your code (instead of list, sets or dictionaries) sprites do work very well. You would as well find by yourself a lot of the niceties OO programming can provide, if you have a class hierarchy for 
all objects that show up in your game, as subclasses of `pygame.sprite.Sprite`. For example, all objects, enemies, protagonists, shots, etc... alike will need to have attributes to record their screen position. But only enemies will need a "point_value" for when they are destroyed, for example. With proper class inheritance you can minimize the amount of code needed.

But to control all that in a game scene, Pygame does not provide a base class - you have to make your own game loop, which may very well be in a function - or in a class you create yourself, which does not inherit from any other Pygame class.

For example, [here](https://github.com/jsbueno/towertower/blob/master/towertower/__init__.py) there is some code I laid out to be the base of a "tower strategy" game. Check as all the objects in scene derive naturally from the `BaseTowerTower` object.